# Standalones label element settings in JSON

Tags: anychart

How do you save standalones label elements settings in JSON? Or is it even possible?

I have all the standard chart settings, i.e., chart type, style, etc., but I am have not figured out a way to do the label constructor.

https://api.anychart.com/8.3.0/anychart.standalones#label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current version of AnyChart 8.3.0 supports serializing only chart instances, but not a stage or standalone objects.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any timeline for adding this feature?

Comment: This feature is not on the roadmap now. We will suggest this improvement to our dev team.